# How to get country name by using longitude and latitude?

Tags: geolocation

I am working with a project, and so far it is possible to get longitude and latitude by using the phones GPS, and saving the values in variables.

I would like to get the names of all countries with help of longitude and latitude, and I have read about "Geocode" and "Geolocation", but I dont know how to implement this in my code.

Someone who can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a "reverse geocoding" solution, which takes lat/lon coordinates and gives you back postal address including country. Reverse geocoding API is offered by all the usual providers -- Google, Bing, Yahoo, etc.